# Command not running on remote server

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-remoting

I am novice in powershell and working on below script to run command on remote server. I am trying to import all the sites from a file which is on the remote server itself. I do not see/get any error but the sites are not imported either.

```
# Set the variables for the remote server and sites.xml file path
$remoteServer = "server06"
$sitesXmlPath = "d:\sites.xml"

$username = 'myuser'
$password = 'thePwd'

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword

# Create a new session to the remote server
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $remoteServer -SessionOption $(New-PSSessionOption -OpenTimeOut 10000) -Credential $credential

# Import the IIS module on the remote server
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Import-Module WebAdministration
}

# Import the sites.xml file on the remote server
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
     
  Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" -ArgumentList '/c', ' add site /in < d:\sites.xml'
}

# Close the session
Remove-PSSession $session
```

What I am missing here?

Update

As per suggestion by Mathias, I tried below but still no error/exception and also no change/update at the target server even though I am using admin creds.

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword

# Create a new session to the remote server
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $remoteServer -SessionOption $(New-PSSessionOption -OpenTimeOut 10000) -Credential $credential

# Import the sites.xml file on the remote server
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
  
  try{ 
      Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/c C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe add site /in < d:\sites.xml'
      write-output "Control is here..."
  
  }catch{
        write-warning "Something went wrong.." #$_
        #continue
  }

}

# Close the session
Remove-PSSession $session
```

Comment: Not sure why you're importing the WebAdministration module then not using it? Why not use `New-Website` from the module? Anyway, does the command work if you execute it locally? Does you user have permission to access the xml file?

Comment: You need to launch `cmd.exe` if you want the input redirector to work: `Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/c C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe add site /in < d:\sites.xml'`